# writing @Test for Hibernate Optimistic locking using @version is not working as expected

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, unit-testing, optimistic-locking

I have simple `User` and `Account` entities, they look like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USERS")
public class User {


    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "USERNAME",length = 50, unique = true)
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ROLE",length = 20)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role;
}
```

And:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACCOUNT")
public class Account {


    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "BALANCE")
    private BigDecimal balance;

    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
    @OneToOne(targetEntity = User.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private User user;

    @Version
    private int version;

}
```

So I tried to write a `@Test` to become sure about it, and it is like:

```
    @Test
    public void test_optimistic_locking_concept() {
        User user = new User("test", "123456", Role.ROLE_USER);
        user = userRepository.save(user);

        Account account = new Account();
        account.setBalance(new BigDecimal("5000"));
        account.setUser(user);
        accountRepository.save(account);

        // fetching account record for different devices
        Account accountInDeviceOne = new Account();
        accountInDeviceOne = accountRepository.findAccountByUser_Username(user.getUsername()).get();

        Account accountInDeviceTwo = new Account();
        accountInDeviceTwo = accountRepository.findAccountByUser_Username(user.getUsername()).get();

        // each device tries to change the account balance by debit/credit
        accountInDeviceOne.setBalance(accountInDeviceOne.getBalance().subtract(new BigDecimal("1500")));
        accountInDeviceTwo.setBalance(accountInDeviceTwo.getBalance().add(new BigDecimal("2500")));

        // The versions of the updated accounts are both 0.
        Assertions.assertEquals(0, accountInDeviceOne.getVersion());
        Assertions.assertEquals(0, accountInDeviceTwo.getVersion());

        // first device request update
        accountInDeviceOne = accountRepository.save(accountInDeviceOne);

        // !Exception!
        accountInDeviceTwo = accountRepository.save(accountInDeviceTwo);
    }
```

But it doesn't throw Exception, as I expected!!

Also it does not increment the `version` field when I do `accountRepository.save(accountInDeviceOne)`.

And in debugger console, as it is shown below, I don't know the reason why they are all pointing to the same resource!!!

[image]

Would someone please help me to understand what is going wrong here and how can I write test for this optimistic Locking Concept?

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: your test method is backed up by single transaction

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov could you please give some more clues or links that how can I achieve multi transaction test?

Comment: You can use transaction template if you are using spring.

Comment: @Sobhan the basic idea is following: your actual goal it is verify hypothesis that if two competing *business transactions* try to modify the same same entity then one of those transactions must fail. That actually means that you need to spawn two threads and somehow synchronise their steps/state in your test scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply update a row in two concurrent threads like this:

```
@SpringBootTest
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class SaveAccountOptimisticallyTest {

@Autowired
private AccountRepository repository;
private Long savedAccountId;

@BeforeEach
public void insertUsers(){
    Account account = Account.builder()
            .balance(BigDecimal.ZERO)
            .build();
    savedAccountId = repository.save(account).getId();

}

@Test
public void test_saving_account_optimistically() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Account account = repository.findById(savedAccountId).orElse(null);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(6000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            account.setBalance(BigDecimal.ONE);
            try {
                repository.save(account);
            }catch (Exception e){
                Assertions.assertEquals(e.getCause(),"StaleObjectStateException");
            }

        }
    });

    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Account account = repository.findById(savedAccountId).orElse(null);
            account.setBalance(BigDecimal.TEN);
            repository.save(account);
        }
    });
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

}

Note that the first runnable will try to update the fetched object 6 seconds after retrieving it from db, and until then, the object's version field will be updated by other thread(t2) and this will cause an OptimisticLock (StaleObjectStateException of Hibernate) exception at t1.

Comment: thank you, it's the correct way of testing concurrent issues

Answer (score 1):

Single session

> First Level Cache: Hibernate first level cache is associated with the Session object. Hibernate first level cache is enabled by default and there is no way to disable it. However hibernate provides methods through which we can delete selected objects from the cache or clear the cache completely. Any object cached in a session will not be visible to other sessions and when the session is closed, all the cached objects will also be lost.

So when you tring find db object by `accountRepository.findAccountByUser_Username` hibernate get it from cache, that's way.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of natural behaviour in JPA. Since Hibernate implements JPA it uses caching and also it has persistence context. So when you load the object (entity) from DB using hibernate the logic is following. When the object is not in persistent context (PC) it is loaded from DB and put to Pc and returned as the result of the call. So when you load it again from other place or in the same method it will returned the same object from PC. Also when you update the object it will update the same object in PC. But the changes made on object will be flushed to DB only when transaction is committed. In your case you are getting the same object from DB twice. So first time object is put to PC from DB and returned and the second time the same object from PC is returned and no call to DB is made. It doesn't matter you have accountInDeviceOne and accountInDeviceTwo because both of them are just reference to the same object in persistent context (PC0. Therefore it doesn't matter on which reference you will made the changes you are changing the same object. Also version is incremented when transaction is committed and changes are flushed to DB. And the transaction is committed after method who created transaction is done. If you want the version to be incremented immediately you can force changes from PC to be flushed to DB by calling flush method in Entity Manager or in case you are using Spring Data JPA also repositories has the same possibility. But that is not usual practice to do that.

Comment: I'd rephrase several sentences: "_Since Hibernate implements JPA it uses caching and also it has persistence context_" - Hibernate used "caching" and persistence context long before JPA came to life. "_flushed to DB only when transaction is committed_" - this will depend on flush mode. Default (AUTO) mode: flush before commit _and_ before any SELECT. "_when you update the object it will update the same object in PC_" - it's the same object. "_But that is not usual practice to do that._" - in tests it is. The usual practice: flush and clear PC before operation-under-test.

Comment: I was talking about default behaviour but of course you can change it via flush mode that is true. Also in spring usual practice is to put Transactional annotation in the class which in test will cause transaction will be rolled back at the end and data will be not stored to DB. This is for me usual practice. Flushing changes manually make sense only in special case like @Sobhan has described. So in this case it is perfectly ok to use it

Comment: "_I was talking about default behaviour but of course you can change it via flush mode that is true._" - yeah, but flushing before SELECT _is_ the default behaviour.

Comment: Yes, you are right